# Scout Eclipse extends Menu

Tags: menu, extends, eclipse-scout

I have one Core project and some other project that extends core.
I know how to extend outline and how to add pages to extended outlines, but my problems are menus.

I would like to extend menu on extended project.

I find some example on web and I think that I understand, but this is not working for me.

What I have is :

```
<extension
     name=""
     point="org.eclipse.scout.rt.extension.client.desktopExtensions">
  <desktopExtension
        class="com.sixt.leasing.pd.scout.client.ui.desktop.DesktopExtension"
        active="true">
  </desktopExtension>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.scout.rt.extension.client.menus">
  <menuContribution
        active="true"
        class="com.sixt.leasing.pd.scout.client.menu.JobRunnerMenu"
        order="22">
     <desktop
           class="com.sixt.leasing.core.scout.client.ui.desktop.Desktop">
     </desktop>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

inside plugin.xml

and my JobRunnerMenu look like :

```
public class JobRunnerMenu extends AbstractExtensibleMenu {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredText() {

    return TEXTS.get("Job");
  }

  @Override
  protected void execAction() throws ProcessingException {

    // TODO  Auto-generated method stub.
    super.execAction();
  }

  @Override
  protected void execToggleAction(final boolean selected) throws ProcessingException {

    // TODO  Auto-generated method stub.
    super.execToggleAction(selected);
  }
}
```

What am I missing ? Why this don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related forum thread: [Multi Modul - Menu Extension](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=934856&goto=1630856&#msg_1630856)

---

I just tested this pattern and it works as expected.

Here is the content of my `plugin.xml` (in the client extension):

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.scout.rt.extension.client.menus">
 <menuContribution
       active="true"
       class="myapp.extension.client.menu.MyMenu"
       order="22">
    <desktop
          class="myapp.client.ui.desktop.Desktop">
    </desktop>
 </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Because the “menuContribution” defines a “desktop” as container, the menu you will add is contributed to the Desktop. Usually those menus are top-level menus and contain child menus.

```
public class MyMenu extends AbstractExtensibleMenu {

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredText() {
    return "My Menu";
  }

  public class MessageBoxTestMenu extends AbstractExtensibleMenu {

    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredText() {
      return "Test MessageBox";
    }

    @Override
    protected void execAction() throws ProcessingException {
      MessageBox.showOkMessage(null, "This is a test", null);
    }
  }
}
```

The result:

[image: Sceenshot]

---

- Are the absolute class names in your XML correct?
- Is your extension correctly started?

Answer (score 0):

Make that your desktop extends the base class [AbstractExtensibleDesktop](https://github.com/eclipse/scout.rt/blob/master/org.eclipse.scout.rt.extension.client/src/org/eclipse/scout/rt/extension/client/ui/desktop/AbstractExtensibleDesktop.java). The regular `AbstractDesktop` class does not load extensions.

Should that be the case, a breakpoint at AbstractExtensibleDesktop#AbstractExtensibleDesktop  should provide for a good starting point to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to mislead with this question.

The above code work, my problem was, that I didn't have added a client in product file. This cause client not to be available so extension could't be added.

Thanks for answer anyway, and yes AbstractExtensibleDesktop is absolutely needed.